# Want to work Nested JSON Object in XPages. Any Reference

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

Is there any help avaiable for using JSON from java class method output to be used in repeater control in XPages.

Please help me I need it a lot.

Want to work Nested JSON Object in XPages. Any Reference or help

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Use **fromJson()** to convert your JSON string into JavaScript array/object structure and put it into repeat's value.

```
<xp:repeat
    id="repeat1"
    rows="30"
    var="element">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var jsonString = '[{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "c"}]';
        fromJson(jsonString)
    }]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:text
        escape="true"
        id="computedField1"
        value="#{element.name}">
    </xp:text>
    <br />
</xp:repeat>
```